# Django search only gets saved locally

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

So I have a website where I compare clothing from multiple sites. I recently implemented a search function. But the searches only get saved to my database (postgresql) when I test locally. Am I missing something?
Model:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    search = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.search)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Searches'
```

views.py:

```
from . import models

def new_search(request):
    search_item = models.Search()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print(request.POST)
        search_item.search = request.POST.get('search')
        search_item.save()
```

form in base.html:

```
<div class="navbar" id="searchcontainer">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'new_search' %}" class="row search-input" id="demo-2" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input style="color: white" class="col-lg-12" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new_search', views.new_search, name='new_search')
]
```

Comment: What is it that you're expecting it to do?

Comment: Saving the search from the user to the database

Comment: But you said it is already saving the search to the database? "searches only get saved to my database"

Comment: Yes when I test it locally. But it doesnt save the searches when a perform a query on https://www.casualspotter.com/.